# How to determine why a Python process is being killed on an EC2 instance while downloading files?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a Python script that downloads files from Google's OpenImages dataset. When I run this script on a free-tier EC2 instance the process is unceremoniously killed as it's downloading.

My assumption is that the script is reaching a download limit of some sort, perhaps a transfer rate or a total inbound amount. The amount of data I'm downloading is less than 2GB.

The Python process is killed hard and the downloaded files are left around in the `/tmp` directory (I am downloading into a temporary directory created via Python's `tempfile` module).

How can I determine the cause of this issue? Where can I look for a log of the cause of the process kill?

Comment: I would start with /var/log/kern.log to see if there is a reason why the kernel is killing the process.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "EC2 free instance". It is exactly the same EC2 instance as anyone would be allocated. The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount that only impacts what is charged. It does not impact the resources provided.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @John Rotenstein, good point. I have edited the title accordingly.